# Making div heights equal without display table property

Tags: html, css

In the following code, the left both divs have different heights (not fixed). Is there a way to make height of div with the less height equal to the height of div with high height without using the CSS `table` property or javascript?

PS. There is no reason not to use table property, I just want to know if theres any alternative.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">less content</div>
    <div class="right">more content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 30px 100px;
}
.left{
    background: yellow;
    width: 50px;  
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.right{
    background: brown;
    width: 50px;
    float:left;  
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vv2Ue/

Comment: This question has been asked HUNDREDS of times already. Go look at an existing answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=equal+height+DIVs

Comment: I would think `height:100%` would do the trick but no.

Comment: height:100% will not work unless all parents have height:100% as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy equal height DIVs without JavaScript possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616912/easy-equal-height-divs-without-javascript-possible)

Comment: @Diodeus "100% to all parents" applies if you want 100% of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tackled this issue today.  Checkout the following resource: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/

I like the last suggestion, which basically creates the illusion of equal heights.

**Html**

```
<div id="container-outer">
    <div id="container-inner">

        <div id="sidebar">
            <p>Sidebar</p>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <p>Main content</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container-outer {
        float:left;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #eee;
    }

    #container-inner {
        float:left;
        background: #555;
        position: relative;
        right:75%;
    }

    #sidebar {
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        position: relative;
        left: 75%;
    }

    #content {
        float: left;
        width: 75%;
        position: relative;
        left: 75%   
    }
```