# How to make all my div's same height based on breathing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

I'm troubled by a reoccurring problem when trying to make grid styled websites, how do I make all the divs on a row the same height depending on the tallest div in that row. One of the divs will contain a set of divs that will need to stretch based on that height and auto fill so everything moves together.

Setting the Divs to the same height has to be based on what content is inside the div itself. For example as the text box resizes the picture should also keep the same height and then all the 'icons' should stretch and keep the same height too.

Here is what I currently have:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="half">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce at ipsum tortor. Etiam ut lacus auctor, venenatis mauris vitae, scelerisque dolor. Mauris pulvinar purus libero, eget congue sem lobortis vitae.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="quater">
    <img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/6yo87o.jpg"></img>
  </div>

  <div class="quater social">
    <div class="third">Icon</div>
    <div class="third">Icon</div>
    <div class="third">Icon</div>
    <div class="third">Icon</div>
    <div class="third">Icon</div>
    <div class="third">Icon</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

The css:

```
.half {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.quater {
  width: 25%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

.third {
  width: 33.33333333%;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

img {width: 100%;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/atp1agmk/4/

And here is my desired outcome:

[image]

I don't mind if it has to be done via JavaScript either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy equal height DIVs without JavaScript possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616912/easy-equal-height-divs-without-javascript-possible)

Comment: No as i'm in need of divs that stretch based on an undefined height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container{
 display: flex;
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.quater {
  width: 25%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.third {
  width: 33.33333333%;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.social {
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: stretch;
}
img {width: 100%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="half">
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce at ipsum tortor. Etiam ut lacus auctor, venenatis mauris vitae, scelerisque dolor. Mauris pulvinar purus libero, eget congue sem lobortis vitae.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="quater">
<img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/6yo87o.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="quater social">
<div class="third">Icon</div>
<div class="third">Icon</div>
<div class="third">Icon</div>
<div class="third">Icon</div>
<div class="third">Icon</div>
<div class="third">Icon</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/atp1agmk/20/

Comment: Is there a way to make the icon text (it will be an Icon or an image) centered to the middle of the resizing box using 'flex'

Comment: fiddle updated - [https://jsfiddle.net/atp1agmk/22/](https://jsfiddle.net/atp1agmk/22/).. flex applied to `.third` also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` css property to achive your requirement.

[Here is the Example](https://jsfiddle.net/atp1agmk/16/) . You can comment if you need other way.

Comment: Your example doesn't replicate what i need and flex doesn't work for me as i cant set a height on the containing div since it depends on the content inside.

Comment: Looks like its half there the icon boxes don't stretch till the max height of the div rather the width.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with flex like this

```
.half {
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.quater {
   width: 25%;
   background: red;
   float: left;
}

.third {
   width: calc(100% / 3);
   height: calc(100% / 2);
   background: blue;
   float: left;
   color: white;
}

img {width: 100%; height: 100%;}

.container {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: can you explain to me the calc(100% / 2) css and if that is friendly with the use of margins and paddings to create spacing between each of the divs?

Comment: the calc() function performs a calculation to be used as the property value. you can write expression inside it, if each of items will have let's say 5px right margin you can set width as follows `width: calc(100% / 3 - 5px)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Check which div height is greater and apply that to all divs.
Try this out
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nikhila/jv2jfuwL/